# How to use ASUS AC68 PCI wireless card

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, asus

There's lots of people/places talking about how to get this card to function. 
None of it works for me.

Most of it, has been along the lines of grabbing some broadcom stuff off a repo, then your drivers will be in the additional drivers page.

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

That's sadly the only one I can remember trying (sorry, in and out of hospital, with lots of pain killers. Details are hard for me right now)
But all things yield no results.

Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit budgie environment.

Thank you in advance to anybody who can help me not need this 200 foot cable, just to have internet.

Alright, first little update on my problem...
Some further research on my own time, PCI ID 14e4:42a0 and BCM4360 are for my card, and reveal numerous amounts of information, most notably I've been looking through [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
Nothing has managed to get the card to be read by the system.  Windows can read it fine however, so I know it is in fact functional.

```
 lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD9x0/RX980 Host Bridge [1002:5a14] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD9x0/RX980 Host Bridge [1002:5a14]
00:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GFX port 0) [1002:5a16]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 0) [1002:5a18]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 1) [1002:5a19]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 2) [1002:5a1a]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 3) [1002:5a1b]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:0a.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 5) [1002:5a1d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:0b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD990 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GFX2 port 0) [1002:5a1f]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:0d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP2 Port 0) [1002:5a1e]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1002:4391] (rev 40)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1043:84dd]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385] (rev 42)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385]
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383] (rev 40)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1043:854b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller [1002:439d] (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller [1002:439d]
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge [1002:4384] (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller [1002:4399]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller [1002:4399]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:16.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
00:16.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0 [1022:1600]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1 [1022:1601]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2 [1022:1602]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3 [1022:1603]
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4 [1022:1604]
    Kernel driver in use: fam15h_power
    Kernel modules: fam15h_power
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5 [1022:1605]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] [10de:17c8] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] [1043:8548]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 High Definition Audio [10de:0fb0] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM200 High Definition Audio [1043:8548]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
02:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1043:84b7]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82583V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:150c]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 82583V Gigabit Network Connection [1043:8457]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b21:1142]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller [1043:85bf]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b21:1142]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller [1043:85bf]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
06:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1043:84b7]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

Comment: The output of `lspci -knn` would be helpful

Comment: Ah yes.  Sorry.  Added that

Comment: We don't see your wireless device in the list. Is it seated correctly in the PCI slot? Is it enabled or disabled in the BIOS? Is it defective?

Comment: Yes, and I currently dual boot, until I can solve this.  It's active and working perfect on Windows 10. Doesn't exist on Linux.
It was also a massive pain to get it to even exist on Windows as well.
It can't be read at all, without it's drivers. Which... I managed to get working on Windows, but seemingly impossible on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling secure boot in BIOS, followed by reinstalling everything. Suddenly it all began to work.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcwml-kernel-source
```

A quick reboot inbetween...

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Once more, a reboot.

Each time I boot up, first thing I checked was the network status on the tray. This time, immediately on login, it already was displaying wireless options for me. 
Checked through additional drivers, lspci, iwconfig, etc, etc. Everything is now showing the card as existing (and functioning)

Secure boot seems to have been preventing it from functioning.

Not knowledgeable enough on the subject to say anything else... Such as why.  Maybe a comment will explain, sadly I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

On my Clevo N240WU laptop I had the same symptom like you (Wi-Fi card not recognized in Linux and not shown in lspci output). I tried different kernels (4.10, 4.13; all the same).

This only happened when I used legacy BIOS. When using UEFI the Wi-Fi card worked.

Comment: Sadly, I am using UEFI all along.